# Does iPhone OS distinguish between foreground and background threads?

Tags: iphone, multithreading

Does iPhone OS distinguish between foreground and background threads?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the notion of the main thread, where all UIKit and Core Graphics calls have to come from. I suppose you could say the main thread is a foreground thread and all other threads in your app are background threads.

You can start a background thread with `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` on `NSObject`. If you need to do some work on the main thread (eg. do some UI stuff), you can use `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`. If you need to check if your code is currently running on the main thread, you can use `[NSThread isMainThread]`.

Answer (score 1):

`[NSThread isMainThread]`